# C++ Database Connection

Tags: c++, sql

I need to connect to a database with c++, I have tried to use mySql++, mySql connector, and a few others however I am unable to get them running, I've tried the tutorials but I can't seem to get them right. VS doesn't see the files that I try to include.

Anyways, Is there a somewhat easy way to connect to a database using c++ without needing to download a ton of files or api's. and if so could you please provide a link to a tutorial, ive tried using ODBC, however I don't think ive been doing it right as it shows a ton of errors in my code.

any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you were trying to connect to a mysql instance? (In other words, what database are you using?)

Comment: Depends on the DBs. There's special library for MySQL (in the official site), there OCCI - for Oracle, ODBC - for some universal like MS SQL, Informix, etc.

Comment: Its an oracle database, with a mysql interface, ive connected to it before with java(jdbc) and c#(odbc) however Ive had no luck with c#

Comment: "Its an oracle database, with a mysql interface" O.O I don't know what does this mean. Anyway, you should be more specific - what means "does not work", what errors do you get, etc.

Answer (score 1):

How about [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/). It is just a header file so far away from tons of files. And all you need is the libraries depending on the DB you want to connect to.

Comment: Didn't know about OTL, nice suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

ODBC is a little bare metal - surely there are some more accessable ADO classes (you might need MDAC)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the ODBC headers are included with VS, so I don't think OP's been trying to use that.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to know what kind of database you have to connect to. It does matter, as you won't use the same API to connect to a MySQL database, or to a SQLite one, or Oracle, or Postgres, or SQL Server ...

Then, have a look at the library that allows acces to the database. And make sure that the database is actually present!

Answer (score 0):

C++ Standard doesn't has native database support. You cannot connect to a database using C++ without database/platform specific libraries. Such as [this](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Connector_C++) or [this one](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/), if you want to connect to MySQL server.

Comment: Ive Tried using the mySql, however when i try to add the include directories into VS, its unable to find them. when using MySql++ it shows errors that it is unable to find the header files within the files of Mysql++

Comment: @user777904, probably you should ask another question with exact description of which errors did you have with mysql++, which version of VS have you used and other details.

Comment: Im using VS2010, its showing an error: cannot open source file"mysql_version.h" however the file is in the directory